# startBluetoothSco() throws Security Exception (BROADCAST_STICKY) on ICS

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I have a stacktrace sent in by a user with ICS.

On my Froyo device everything is working fine, but the user apparently gets the Permission Denial when `AudioManager.startBluetoothSco()` is called...
I have no idea why this is happening - I know the Broadcast for ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED *is sticky*, but it is not the app that is sending it, so it should not need the permission...

Below is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: broadcastIntent() requesting a sticky 
broadcast from pid=15341, uid=10064 requires android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.startBluetoothSco(IAudioService.java:1090)
at android.media.AudioManager.startBluetoothSco(AudioManager.java:975)
at de.bulling.smstalk.libs.utils.AudioUtils.startBluetoothSco(AudioUtils.java:164)
at de.bulling.smstalk.Services.TTS.speakIt(TTS.java:151)
at de.bulling.smstalk.Services.TTS.onInit(TTS.java:83)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:627)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.access$1000(TextToSpeech.java:52)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:1279)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

/edit: I could reproduce the issue, and it doesn't matter if I start the service with `START_STICKY` or not.

Comment: Is there any reason to not want to include the permission?

Comment: No, I now included it for the next update, but it *should not be needed* for this function. So there must be something wrong. Argh - so far ICS brought so many issues....

Comment: Can you reproduce it in an emulator? Or is it only happening on a Galaxy Nexus? It could be a device specific problem?

Comment: I could reproduce it with the 4.0.3 Emulator (not with the 4.0), and with the permission added it works. But the permission is for *sending* Sticky Intents, not for *receiving*, so maybe this is a bug in 4.0.3?

Comment: I have same problem with my app. Something was changed in new version of Android. Why there is no info from google about changes? =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only workaround is to add this permission to your app to get it working on ICS..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

There is an issue logged [here on OHAP](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25136) for this defect in ICS